# Laravel Livewire Routings wont show the right blade

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-livewire

When i go the the Homepage it only shows my Header when i didn't even set anywhere my header yet. It won't show my Startpage even when i set it in the routings and did

```
php artisan optimize
```

When i deleted the Header component it gave a error that it tries to get the header component that i dont want to use

My routings

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/register', function () {
    return view('register');
});
Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::get('/', App\Http\Livewire\Startpage::class);
```

My Startpage that I want to show on the homepage

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Startpage extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.startpage');
    }
}
```

My header that I do not want to show yet but it still does

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Header extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.header');
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you probably render the header in your layout or in that startpage component?

Comment: I did an mount function on the startpage component and that works but the render does not work

Comment: Please share your `livewire.startpage` file.